# Let $a<b$ be real numbers and consider the set $T=\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$. Show $\sup T=b$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a<b$ be real numbers and consider the set $T=\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$. Show $\sup T=b$. So, I need to prove that $b \ge t$ for all $t \in T$, that $b$ is upper bound. Next is to show for any other upper bound $r$ for $T$, $t \le r$. Then, $\sup T=b$. 
 
To prove that $b$ is an upper bound, consider $t$, $t \in T$, since intersection of $Q$ and $[a,b]$ is simply the set $T'=[x \in Q : a \le x \le b]$, therfeore, for every value of $t \in T$, $b \ge t$, hence, $b$ is upper bound of $T$. 
To prove second part, let $r$ be some upper bound of $T$, then $t \le r$ for all $t \in T$. Since, $r$ is upper bound of $T$ and $b$ is element of $T$, therefore, $b \le r$. Therefore, $b$ is least upper bound. Proof complete.

I know it is a work of rookie but I am learning. Please suggest if I am wrong somewhere, and also help me out by suggesting  precise mathematical language wherever I could have used to make it look really like a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake happens at

> and $b$ is element of $T$,

because $b$ can be irrational. and then the statement above isn't true (for example, if $b=\sqrt 2$).

You have proven correctly that $b$ is an upper bound (it could be done more quickly by simply saying that if $x\in T$, then $x\in [a,b]$, and if $x\in [a,b]$, then clearly, $x\leq b$, but nevertheless, the proof is OK).

Your proof of least upper bound is perfectly OK if $b$ is rational, but in that case, $b$ is the *maximum* of $T$ and maximums are **always** also the supremums of their sets.

---

So, the work is still ahead of you. You now have to prove that if $b$ is **irrational** and $r$ is some upper bound of $T$, then $r\geq b$.

To do that, here's a **hint**:

Try to prove it by contradiction. If $r<b$, can you figure out a way to show that $r$ cannot be the upper bound of $T$? (that would mean finding some element of $T$ that is larger than $r$, i.e. that is an element of $(r,b]$)

Comment: Why can't I use the fact that $T=\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$ contains only rational numbers between $[a,b]$. Rational intersection real must be rational only?

Comment: @SEMICASA $T$ contains only rational numbers, yes. But $b$ may not be a rational number (and, note, $b$ **may not be** an element of $T$). For example, if $a=0$ and $b=\sqrt 2$, then $b$ **is not an element** of $T$. The task explicitly states *Let $a<b$ be real numbers*.

Comment: Let there be some $e=b-r>0$. Since we have taken $r<b$, therefore, this implies $r+e<r+2e$ giving $e<2e$ which can not be true. Therefore, there is no $r$ such that $r<b$ hence $b$ is least upper bound. Is this right way to prove contradiction is wrong?

Comment: @SEMICASA Why can't $e<2e$ be true? It's perfectly true for all positive numbers... Again, take a look at my hint.

Comment: yes I was in hurry to prove and made such a mistake. If that is true than contradiction is correct and that should be the case if I am proving $b$ to be least upper bound.

Comment: @SEMICASA No, the proof is nowhere near good. Try again, and *slowly* this time, and please, take a look at my hint.

Comment: Let there be an element $x \in T$, therefore, $x \le b$. Now since $r<b$, using both the facts we have $x+r < 2b$ => $r<b+b-x$, let there be some $e=b-x>0$, then $r<b+e$. Hence, $r$ can not be an upper bound of $T$. I feel happy this time, I think I have got it this time. :-)

Comment: @SEMICASA Again, the proof is not good. Sure, you proved that $r<b+e$, but since you already know that $r<b$, this is nothing new, and especially, it doesn't imply that $r$ is not an upper bound of $T$. Again, you didn't listen to my hint.

Comment: How do I find an element in $T$ which is greater than $r$. I understood the hint but I am unable to manipulate it to the desired result.

Comment: @SEMICASA You need to prove that there exists a rational number in $(r,b]$.

Comment: @SEMICASA If you are tired, go rest. I won't solve this any more than I already did, as even a basic look at a textbook should be enough to solve it.

Comment: Supposing the fact that I have shown $r$ is not an upper bound of $T$ for the case $r<b$. How does it prove that for some upper bound $r$, $r \ge b$ which I wanted to prove.

Comment: @SEMICASA Because if $r$ is not an upper bound for $r<b$, this means that all upper bounds must be larger or equal than $b$ (because they cannot be smaller). You seem very confused about the subject. I advise you to actually sit down and talk to someone (like your teacher) for a solid session.